# S3 Public Access Alternatives

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been learning AWS for a little while now and there's one thing that just confuses me.

Let's say I own a app like Instagram (Lol but still) and my users upload a lot of images on my app. Now I take them and store it on a s3 bucket through whatever means. Now the images are stored securely on S3 and the URL of the image is stored on my DB so that my users can easily access the image from the app.

Now, for the image to be accessible everywhere [ Mobile Apps, Desktop App and Web App ], I have to make the bucket public and all the images inside it public so that any application can access  the image through the URL. But S3 recommends us not to make the bucket and it's contents public.

I tried not making the bucket public and just set a CORS configuration such like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.trailer2you.herokuapp.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.t2ytest-private.herokuapp.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.t2ybeta.herokuapp.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

But this also doesn't work. The only way all the apps can access the image through the URL is to make the bucket and all it's contents public through a policy like

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1598785179613",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1598785170418",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "{my ARN}",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is what S3 discourages us from doing. Is there any other alternative to achieve something like this. There must be something but I'm new to cloud and I'm not able to find the proper resource for this in the documentation. If someone could point me out to a documentation for something similar to this case, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**.

There are several ways to provide access to a bucket:

- Permissions on an IAM User or IAM Role (good for staff members and software, but not for end-users)
- A **Bucket Policy** that makes a bucket public (good for web sites, but not for private content)
- A **pre-signed URL** that provides time-limited access to a private object

It sounds like a pre-signed URL is best for your situation. Imagine a photo-sharing website:

- A user authenticates to the application
- The user requests access to a photo
- The application checks whether the user is entitled to view the photo
- If so, the application generates a pre-signed URL that has a limited validity period (eg 5 minutes)
- The user follows this link, or the link is embedded in a web page (eg as a `<img>` tag)
- Amazon S3 processes the request by verifying that the pre-signed URL is correctly signed and that the time period has not expired. If everything is okay, it returns the object (file). If it is not okay, then it says "Access Denied"
- User A then shares a photo with User B. The application updates this information in its database
- User B can then request access to the photo via the same process

For more details, see: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: Yeah. Makes sense, but I have one follow up question. Ideally to generate a presigned URL, it's technically a network call to AWS S3 to generate a url in runtime. Doesn't this put a technical overhead at scale? I'm serving 1M posts per hour and let's say a presigned url has validity for an hour. So every hour, I'll need to generate pre-signed URL's for each of the 1M photos which could have unnecessary overhead on my system.

Comment: Generating a pre-signed URL can be done locally with no API call. It's basically generating a hash using the Secret Key. It only takes a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Excuse me but how could I have a secret locally? I don't understand how you can securely pre-sign a URL without using an API call.

Comment: @EgonBolton Creating a secret requires the URL to the object and any conditions to apply (eg limit by IP address). This is then hashed using the Secret Key. Finally, a URL is created that contains the URL, the Access Key (which can be shown publicly) and the hash 'signature'. This does not require an API call to create. The code creating the pre-signed URL requires knowledge of the Secret Key.

Answer (score 2):

To complement's @John's answer, you could also use server your images from the bucket using CloudFront (CF) through **Origin Access Identity** (OAI):

- [How do I use my CloudFront distribution to restrict access to an Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/)
- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)
- [Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Using OAI with CF you can keep your **bucket fully private**, and force your users to access your images through CF only. The use of CF would also speed up the downloads as it is AWS's content delivery network, closer to the end users than S3.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should have looked into CloudFront before posting the question, but thanks for the great resources. I'll definitely check them out and see if I can incorporate them into my services.

Comment: @SriramR be aware that [*"`aws:referer` should not be used to prevent unauthorized parties from making direct AWS requests."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-referer)  That's not what it's for, and it's unfortunate that the example in the S3 documentation does not seem to call this out. The same is true of CORS -- it is not intended to secure your content.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for printing this out. I removed that section from my answer.