# Is there any alternative to pre signed url approach for uploading/downloading images from the s3 aws bucket?

Tags: react-native

I am using react native and node js. A newly generated pre signed url for images are getting expired, as you know, it will after 7 days. So is there any solution to that? Or is there any other better appraoch?

Answer (score 0):

If content you are sharing are public static resource(images, scripts etc) - **bucket policy with public access** is best for you. In case your content is private, **pre signed URLs** should be used.
Please consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63656918/3240320).